# Remove iPad sources in XCode.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

In xCode, I switched my target settings to universal out of curiousity. Then I switched it back to iPhone. When I load up my app in the iPad under universal and iPhone targets, the app crashes. I suspect it might have something to do with the added files for iPad support. How can i remove the iPad target entirely from my app? The only devices I want to support is the iPhone and the iPod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning your project, then building?

Comment: So set the target as iPhone, clean and rebuild project?

Comment: Didn't work, but I fixed it by editing info.plist. After cleaning, it still holds a reference to MainWindow-iPad.xib. Just get rid of that and your all good. Thanks a bunch sergio!